# Prove or disprove: If $E[Y]>E[X]$, then $F_X(z)>F_Y(z)$ for some $z$.

Tags: probability, statistics

Prove or disprove:

> (a) If $F_X(z)>F_Y(z)$ for all $z$, then $E[Y]>E[X]$.

By definition

$E[X] = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} [1-F_X(z)]dz + \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{0} [F_X(z)]dz$

Given that $F_X(z)>F_Y(z)$ then

$$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} [-F_X(z)]dz < \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} [-F_Y(z)]dz$$

$$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} [1-F_X(z)]dz < \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} [1-F_Y(z)]dz$$

$$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} [1-F_X(z)]dz - \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{0} [F_X(z)]dz < \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} [1-F_Y(z)]dz - \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{0} [F_Y(z)]dz$$

$$E[X]<E[Y]$$

> (b) If $E[Y]>E[X]$, then $F_X(z)>F_Y(z)$ for all $z$.

A simple counterexample

$$P[Y=1]=0.5 , P[Y=4]=0.5$ then $E[Y] = 3$$

$$P[X=2]=0.98 , P[X=6]=0.02 $ then $E[X] = 2.08$$

$$E[Y] > E[X]$$

**but**

$$F_X(4)<F_Y(4)$$

> (c) If $E[Y]>E[X]$,then $F_X(z)>F_Y(z)$ for some $z$.

Can someone help me with this? Intuitively, I think that it's true

> (d) If $F_X(z)=F_Y(z)$ for all $z$, then $P[X=Y]=1$.

If $F_X(z)=F_Y(z)$ then $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution by counterexample

$$P[Y=1]=0.5 , P[Y=2]=0.5$$

$$P[X=1]=0.5 , P[X=2]=0.5$$

**but**

$$P[X=Y]= (1/2)$$

> (e) If $F_X(z)>F_Y(z)$ for all $z$, then $P[X<Y]>0$.

$$P[X\leq{}z] > P[Y\leq{}z]$$

$$P[X<z] > P[Y<z]$$

$$P[X-Y<z] > P[Y-Y<z]$$

$$P[X-Y<{}0] > P[0<0]$$

$$P[X-Y<0] > 0$$

$$P[X<Y] > 0$$

> (f) If $Y=X+1$, then $F_X(z)=F_Y(z+1)$ for all $z$

$$F_X(z) = P[X\leq{}z] = P[X+1\leq{}z+1] = P[Y \leq{}z+1] = F_Y(z+1)$$

Any suggestion?

Thank so much, have an excellent day

Comment: Isn't (c) the contrapositive of modified version of (a)? I think you can still prove $(a)$ by replacing $<$ with $\leq$. (c) is equivalent to: if for all z, $F_X(z)\leq F_Y(z)$ then $E[X]\leq E[Y]$ which is what I call modified (a). Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes I typed wrong but anyway if for all z, we have this relation between distributions, i.e. for all $z$, $F_X(z)\leq F_Y(z)$ then you get $E[Y]\leq E[X]$ which is contradiction. I posted this as an answer.

Comment: @ArashBeh       Thanks you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for all $z$, $F_X(z)\leq F_Y(z)$ then you can use the same proof as (a) to show $E[Y]\leq E[X]$. But this contradicts $E[Y] > E[X]$ so the assumption was wrong and for some $z$, $F_X(z)> F_Y(z)$.